# WPF ListView with GridView styling ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

Ok I started to post a question but in the midst of posting I had an idea that turned out to fix it... I'm posting with an answer in case it saves someone else some frustration.

I'm trying to make a custom style for ListViewItem and within a ListView that has a GridView.  Here is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="StListViewItemBase" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource BrSelectableItemHover}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource BrSelectableItemHover}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then I have a ListView like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StListViewItemBase}">            
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="test">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleObject}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="test 2">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleObject}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

however, when I run it I get the columns, but in the items list it just gives 'TestApp.SampleObject' readout for each item, and not even in each column, just once for each.  If I remove the item container style it works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

So I generated this style by going into Blend, creating a ListViewItem, and editing a copy of the template.  However it turns out the template is different if it's inside a GridView than if it isn't...  I had to create a ListView with a GridView, THEN a ListViewItem inside it and then edit that style.  Here is the revised style that works:

```
<Style x:Key="StListViewItemBase" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#Artifakt Element Light" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11pt" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrDarkText}" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#75FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrSelectableItemHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrSelectableItemHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hopefully that saves someone else some frustration...